# Manipulating text in a rich text editor using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, contenteditable, slatejs

I have a chrome extension content script running on a page. This page has a slateJs editor (a complex and highly nested `contentEditable` `<div>`).

All my extension needs to do, is take all the text inside the editor, and replace it with some custom text. How can I achieve this?

With a normal `<input>` , I just set the `value` prop and emitted an `input` `Event` on the element which did the work, but this does not seem to work.

Have also tried some complex `Range` and `Selection` manipulations, but with no success

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).